# How to slide label text and image same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uilabel

I have created slider in my app, I want to image and label both are slide same time.

This time image slider working proper but label slider do not work. i want a label text slide how to work. please help. Thank you

## My code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edutimeapp.com/toshow/chamber-of-commerc/ws/fetch_event.php"]];
response =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
 }

 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
[response appendData:data];
NSLog(@"error receving data %@",response);
 }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

 }
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;

 NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
 NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
NSLog(@"response data %@",json);

NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
img_ary =[[results valueForKey:@"slider"]valueForKey:@"imageurl"];
 NSLog(@"images fetch %@",img_ary);

des_ary =[[results valueForKey:@"slider"]valueForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"label text %@",des_ary);

for (NSString *line in des_ary) {
    NSLog(@"%@", line);
    
    self.label.text=line;
    
}

NSMutableArray *arrayImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *strImageUrl in img_ary) {
    [arrayImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImageUrl]]]];
}

self.img.animationImages = arrayImages;
_img.animationDuration=10;
_img.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[_img startAnimating];
 }
```

## Label slider code

```
 NSMutableArray *arraylabel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *line in des_ary) {
    NSLog(@"%@", line);
    [arraylabel addObject:line];
    self.label.text=arraylabel;
    [self.label sizeToFit];
    self.label.center = self.view.center;
    self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame = self.label.frame;
                         frame.origin.x = 10;
                         self.label.frame = frame;
                     } completion:nil];
    
    
}
```

Comment: where is your label slider code

Comment: but what the meaning of that **but label slider do not work**

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251506/is-there-a-way-to-animate-changing-a-uilabels-textalignment  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680658/how-to-animate-the-movement-of-a-uilabel

Comment: do you mean  to show download percentage on Lable ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please see my updated question (Label slider code) , I used but don't change label text

Comment: put some static texts array , you are putting wrong text (you are giiving array to label text)   self.label.text=arraylabel;

Comment: @JagveerSingh I want dynamic array put in label text. Because label text get by web server

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Are you there? please solve my problem

Comment: you mean you want to get array of event_title from webservice then change it on lable text

Comment: you can get one text from webservice and change only one lable text. M I right ?

Comment: want to get all texts in array then change all lable texts with Animation

Comment: yes it is possible , you want change lable text from array of texts, but you need to show one text at a same time . right ?

Comment: first check your array of text is containing data you needed.

Comment: @ankurkumawat please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make globalCounter as global variable, make sure test data you get

```
globalCounter=0;
if(nameArray.count>0){

    [self changeLable];

}
```

then

```
-(void)changeLable{

    if(!(globalCounter<nameArray.count)){
        return;
    }


    NSLog(@"globalCounter %d",globalCounter);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                     animations:^{


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [lblTitle setText:[nameArray objectAtIndex:globalCounter]];
                         globalCounter++;

                         [self performSelector:@selector(changeLable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

                     }];


}
```

Comment: I am using your code, change label text only one time but i want loop wise repeat  label text

Comment: I am still waiting your reply. Please reply and solve my problem

Comment: yes this loop will check ur array count then change lable text

Comment: Yes I accepted your answer but don't repeat my array

Comment: if(!(globalCounter<nameArray.count)){
globalCounter=0;
       
    }

Comment: Thankyou so much dear sir, your code is working good. thanks a lot :)